# When building Xcode app, get error "#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h> file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I did pod install and then opened xcworkspace file and now I'm getting errors of "#import  file not found for example.

Is there something i can do to fix this? Trying all day

Comment: Try after restart the xcode

Comment: Reinstall pod file again

Comment: by doing pod install?

Comment: yes by doing pod install

Comment: still not working, should under frameworks folder, should there be a libPods-AppName.a exist or a Pods_appName.framework

Comment: can you please add the pod name here?

Comment: Try to build once(command+B) and then import file

Answer (score 0):

You can try to using bridging header.

Comment: how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the pod name from your Podfile and try pod install. This time this will remove all the parse components from your project. After that add pod name for parseUI with correct version number and try pod install.

Comment: i have completely deintegrated pods and redid it and still not working

Comment: the libPods-APP.a is red if that matters.

Comment: Can you pls paste the pod name here?

Comment: Did you added pod name as "pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.2'" ?

Comment: Pls add Pod name as pod 'ParseUI', '~> 1.2'

Comment: right now im getting this ld: library not found for -lBolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: This error is because of some missing libraries in your project. Did you deintegrated pods before installing the new one? Check in your Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. Any of your framework may had been removed from there.

Add it and Clean and Build your project. It should work fine.

Comment: is this correct to have under my app target? libPods-App.a?

Comment: You need to add this under Link Binary With Libraries

Comment: Are you using Swift?

Comment: im still getting this ld: library not found for -lBolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)